# How to use Transforms on web.config so debug connection string is different than production

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Can i get an example of how I would use transforms to replace my connection string so that production has the following connection string, and debug has the second one?

```
<add name="SomethingEntities" 
         
connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.SomethingEntity.csdl|res://*/DataModel.SomethingEntity.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.SomethingEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server;initial catalog=Something;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

In debug mode, I'd like my connectionstring to be

````
<add name="Something_Dev_Entities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.Something_Dev_Entity.csdl|res://*/DataModel.Something_Dev_Entity.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.Something_Dev_Entity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server;initial catalog=Something_Dev;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>```
````

Comment: If I may, what version of c# are you in?
But in general, Web.Debug.Config will load automatically in the "debug" environment.
If you are in modern c#, I would recommend moving over to appSetting.json. Much much easier to read, modify and organize.

Comment: It seems like 4.7 according to the webconfig file, assuming you're asking about the Framework.

Comment: Gotcha, my $0.02, but if you have the option, prefer moving over to .net core. It will give you access to a lot of modern features that are very useful. Especially if you are, as your name implies, new to programming. .Net Core 6 is a good place to start, it is a LTS branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you Should create a configuration transforms to manage different settings.

for example, you can create two new config files:

- **Web.Debug.config**: This is the transform file for the debug environment.
- **Web.Release.config**: This is the transform file for the production environment.

for each new files you should create your custom configuration like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionString"
       connectionString="Debug_Connection_String_Here"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionString"
       connectionString="Production_Connection_String_Here"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When you publish your application, select the appropriate build configuration (Debug or Release) in Visual Studio. The transformation will be applied during the publishing process, and the connection string in the Web.config file will be replaced with the correct one for the selected environment.

Comment: Exactly the right answer. To note, in .Net Core, the functionality is very similar, except its appSettings.Debug.json etc etc.

Comment: I was making it way too complicated.